# Speeding up SVM (Model trainig)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am relatively new to SVM, i am trying to Train one-class SVM model using 'fitcsvm' function in matlab. 'rbf' (~ gaussian kernel) Kernel function is used.

My data size is around 150k. unfortunately the model trainig time is slow (around 3 min). I use the following line in matlab to train a SVM model

**SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,y,'KernelScale','auto','Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','rbf','Nu',1);**

**X is n*m** Matrix where in the number of the data points (~150k) and m is the Features number (= 2 features)

**Y** is the data lable , where i train a one-class model **y= ones(n,1);**

**Any advice/Suggestions to Speed up the model Training step?**

Thanks

Comment: This is very broad! Keep in mind that kernelSVM is between O(n^2) and O(n^3) complexity-wise (n=n_samples, depends on caching). I'm not sure if this implementation is using libsvm internally (they are mentioning one of those libsvm papers; but not the one i expected), so maybe you will gain something by somehow using libsvm.

Comment: In my personal experience, the matlab integration of [LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is a lot faster than the built in fitcsvm.

Comment: Thanks Sascha and Vahe
LibSVM works well 

Regards;

Answer (score 1):

SVM suffer from scalability and memory issues. Nothing we can do about it, this is the way the algorithm works. There are some attempts to make its computations in parallel, but these are scarce and many times based on (accurate?) approximations. If you have to stick to this particular model, the work in [1](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34638.pdf) provides code for this.

Another suggestion would be trying the linear kernel (which is much more lighter and probably accurate enough for your dataset) [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/), developed by the same team that created LIBSVM (mentioned by sasha in previous comments), which is probably the most complete and optimised SVM for MATLAB.

Good luck!